# Axios.Post is not sending data to mongodb working on node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, mongoose, axios

so I have a POST call, that seems to be working, the only issue is that is not sending the data to the database. See below for import pieces of code: Thanks in advance!

**`module.js`**

```
var mongoose = require ( 'mongoose' );

var CryptoWallet = new mongoose.Schema({
  publicK:{
    bsonType: "String"
  },
  seed:{
    bsonType: "String"
  }
},{
    collection : 'test1a' //
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('test1', CryptoWallet); //Change from test1
```

**`routes.js`**

```
var CryptoWallet = require('../models/CryptoWallet-model');

//Defined store route --Need to get the right functions to generate data
router.route('/add/createCryptoWallet').post(function(req, res){

   var crypto_wallet = new CryptoWallet(req.headers)
     console.log("The cyrptoWallet on create", crypto_wallet);
     //console.log(wallet);
      crypto_wallet.save()
      .then(crypto_wallet =>{
        res.status(200).json({status: 'CryptoWallet addded succesfully'});//,CryptoWalletObject: crypto_wallet
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save CryptoWallet to databse");
      });
});
```

**`main.js`**

```
...
var address = "Ox" + addresses;
                    var seedPhrase = seed;
                    html = html + "<p><b>Address:</b>" + address  + "</p>"; //html = html + "<p><b>Address: </b>0x" + address  + "</p>";        
                }
                document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = html;
                    console.log(seedPhrase)
                    console.log(typeof seedPhrase)
                    console.log(address)
                    console.log(typeof seedPhrase)
                    addToAPI(seedPhrase,address); //address
            }
        });
    });
}
        function addToAPI(seedPhrase,address){
            let NewUser = {
         publicK:address,
                 seed: seedPhrase
             }
      console.log(NewUser);
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/CryptoWallet/add/createCryptoWallet', NewUser)
      .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
                console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

This is the response from the console on the web: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MtJh.png)
and the console on my terminal: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxpgW.png)

Thank you guys, please let me know if I am missing any information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a really dumb mistake, on `routes.js`, changed `bsonType` to `type` and `"string"` to `string`

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.js` you are not getting the object `NewUser` that you are passing in from your `main.js` in POST method. You can get it by using the `req.body` object.

Also, to avoid the warning you should pass the stated object to the `connect` function, something like the following:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@sample.com:port/dbname', { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, unfortunately, is not working. It still looks like my object `NewUser` is not getting passed. Also, thank you for the warning fix, it did work.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(req.body)` in your `routes.js`? You should get your `NewUser` object. So change the `crypto_wallet` object creation: use `req.body` as parameter instead `req.headers`.

Comment: I get `undefined` from `console.log(req.body)`. I changed `req.headers` to `req.body` in my `routes.js`

Comment: Have you installed/configured `body-parser` in your api? You need to do it before route definition.

Comment: I just installed/configured `body-parser`. Now from `console.log(req.body)` is showing my data`{ publicK: '0xc31a31568068963db7b3f022d4beeeba3a658b73',
  seed: 'chicken convince ordinary door slot valve attitude viable draft toddler tornado solution' }`, but is still not reflecting on the db. When I do `console.log(crypto_walet)` it just gives me the _id  created by mongo.

Comment: Just for reference the whole console response is: 
`The cyrptoWallet on create { _id: 5bc36e1e78b6bf4a349ae21a }
{ publicK: '0xc31a31568068963db7b3f022d4beeeba3a658b73',
  seed: 'chicken convince ordinary door slot valve attitude viable draft toddler tornado solution' }`

Comment: Hey @jbarros,  it did help me but it did not solve my whole problem. I posted an answer with the fixes I did in order to solve completely my problem. Thank You for your help!